# VBA run time error 91 Object variable or with block variable not set

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I am totally new to VBA. Currently I am learning how to use vba to create Pivottable and charts. But I am facing the Error 91 problem after debugged my code as below. 
I am trying to count the number of failpartid occurred at certain time, and then draw the pivottable to show the count number. Thank you!

P.S: So I edited and checked my code again, but found out the "PT is nothing" during debugging. I have dim PT at the beginning, does anybody know why?

```
    With .PivotFields("FailPartId") is the line has the error.

   Sub Trial1()
  Dim PTCache As PivotCaches
  Dim PT As PivotTables
  Dim PF As PivotFields
  Dim FinalCol As Long

    FinalCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    'Range("E1:F1").Select
    'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Name = "PivotData"

    Application.Goto Reference:="Trial1"
    'Create the Cache
    Set PTCaches = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase,       SourceData:="ActiveSheet!A1")

    'Create the pivot table
     Set PT = PTCaches.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(1, FinalCol   + 2), TableName:=”PivotTable1”, ReadData:="PivotData")
    'Set the Fields
    With PT
   'Set column field
    With .PivotFields("FailPartId")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Position = 1
   End With
 'Set Row field
     With .PivotFields("ProductionYM")
     .Orientation = xlRowField
     .Position = 1
    End With

 'Set data feild
     ActiveSheet.AddDataField.PivotFields ("FailPartId"), "Count of FailPartId", xlCount
     End With

    End Sub
```

Comment: in what line you have this error?

Comment: Hey I just added the line: With .PivotFields("FailPartId")

Comment: Add this line `MsgBox PT Is Nothing` just before `With PT` . What you will get?

Comment: One problem is in the line a few above: Set PT = PTCaches.CreatePivotTable...  You have never set PTCaches to anything prior to that line (at least not in the code you've provided).  You declared it, but never set it.  And in the line above that, you are setting an undeclared variable: PTCache, which is never referenced again in the code you've provided.

Comment: @simoco It came out the msgbox said True

Comment: Just as an aside, this error is the VBA equivalent of "Null pointer exception". You'll be seeing it a lot of when you work in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

If you have put `Option Explicit` at the top and to **Debug-->Compile VBAProject**, you will solve it yourself.

Replace all `PTCaches` with `PTCache` and then change the line

`Dim PTCache As PivotCaches` to `Dim PTCache As PivotCache`.

Also the `”` may become another issue. `TableName:=”PivotTable1”` is not the same as `TableName:="PivotTable1"`

[image]

Comment: Hey Thanks for pointing out! I tried but the same problem happened again.Is there any possibility that I set the data range wrong, then the code won't be able to create the PivotCache?

Comment: can you step into the macro by selecting a line in the Sub, press <kbd>F8</kbd> and go through the code line by line? You should spot errors easier this way as you can change variables in real time.